# Using a module in Titanium Alloy

Tags: android, titanium, bluetooth-lowenergy, titanium-alloy, ibeacon-android

I am working on a project in Titanium Alloy.
I need to use the Beacon module to scan for beacons using BLE.
My problem is that i can't get the module to work.

I used the *Install mobile module* to install the module and i enabled it in the tiapp.xml file.

This is the code i have at the moment:

```
var Beacons = require('com.logicallabs.beacons');

function doClick(beacon) {
    if(Beacons.BeaconsModule.isEnabled()){
        alert('succes');
    }else{
        alert("suces");
    }
}

$.index.open();
```

The function gets launched when you click a label. The module contains 3 classes. Do you have to specify wich method from which class you have to use?

Also when i start this program i get errors saying `Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager` and `Could not find class 'com.logicallabs.beacons.ScanService$2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly modified code from example app which is included in module which you installed:

```
var Beacons = require('com.logicallabs.beacons');

function log(text) {
    Ti.API.info(text);
}

if (Beacons.isSupported()) {
    log('Bluetooth is supported!');

    if (Beacons.isEnabled()) {
        log('Bluetooth is already enabled!');
    } else {
        log('Bluetooth is disbled; enabling now.');
        // This will eventually fire a stateChanged event with state set to
        // STATE_ON, at which point we start the scanning.
        Beacons.enable();
    }
} else {
    log('Bluetooth LE is not supported.');             
}
```

For more details check documentation and example app. On OSX you can find it in `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.logicallabs.beacons/` directory.

Comment: I still get the errors Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager and Could not find class 'com.logicallabs.beacons.ScanService$2. I am debugging on an android device because i can't get the emulators to work. Could it be a problem with my android?

Answer (score 0):

It will only work if you test on a device with Android API version is >= 18